# how to change the color of "Textview" when i Click the "Toggle Button" in programmatically in Android Studio?

Tags: android

```
tg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (tg.equals("ON")) tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
            else tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0"));



        }
    });
```

"here tg means toggle button object and tv means Textview object"

Comment: simply use `tg.isChecked()` inside `if`

Comment: Thanks Pavneet :) it worked..

Answer (score 1):

Use `tg.isChecked()` like this:

```
if (tg.isChecked()){
     tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5")); // set color 1
   }
else
    tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E0E0E0")); // set color 2
```